# MongoDB Update Document Vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, mongodb

Been following C# tutorials and just converting the syntax to Vb. When I was following the C# tutorial on updating a document, I couldn't convert the syntax.

Specifically, these

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("name", "Juni");
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update
    .Set("cuisine", "American (New)")
    .CurrentDate("lastModified");
```

When trying to use the Filter.Eq() the same way as the tutorial, I get wrong the argument error.

Heres my code of what I've did so far. I've purposely left out connection strings..

```
        Dim collection As IMongoCollection(Of RepReport) = db.GetCollection(Of RepReport)("BDS_Rep_Reports")
        Dim query As IQueryable = From rpt In collection.AsQueryable() Where rpt.IsInSql = False Select rpt
        For Each rpt As RepReport In query
            'Update document and change the InSql column here.
        Next
```

So I basically just want to update each document in the query **one by one** not at the same time.

Comment: Google suggests this seems to be an issue with their .Net driver not playing nicely with VB when it comes to filtering.

Comment: @topshot Hm, the company I work for explicitly writes in vb.net so my hands are tied here abit.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. A simple search for "filter.eq" "visual basic" (or "vb") brings up pretty much nothing but C# and the few VB users were those like yourself wondering how to get it to work. Maybe ask MongoDB support directly if there is such a thing.

Comment: @topshot Right, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any correspondence between the original C# and your VB code.
The VB equivalent is just:

```
'at the top of the file:
Option Infer On

'later within your method:
Dim filter = Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.Eq("name", "Juni")
Dim update = Builders(Of BsonDocument).Update.Set("cuisine", "American (New)").CurrentDate("lastModified")
```

Comment: I thought it would be that simple too.

Its what I did originally but it spits out errors in VB.

Try it yourself.

Comment: @BenDonnelly: If 'Builders' and 'BsonDocument' were readily available types, I would try it, but I don't think I'll be downloading these just to try this.  Regardless, I'm sure the problem is not unique to these types.

Comment: @topshot Yes the c# version works fine which is why it's making me pull my hair out

Comment: Perhaps you can post the full error text along with the full code for that routine.

Comment: Its a syntax error, anyway here it is. http://prntscr.com/bmo9ca The printscreen will show the syntax error and theres no more code to see really apart from connection strings. @topshot